# Vis.js - vis undefined in APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm trying to integrate a `vis.js` functionality into Oracle Application Express but I can't seem to make it work at all.

If I'm running the script separately, it works as it should, but when I'm trying to load the scripts (vis.min.css) / (vis.min.js) in APEX, I get: `SCRIPT5009: 'vis' is undefined` and `SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number` in console.

The above lines lead to the following lines of code:

- in my script:

  ```
  var parsedData = vis.network.convertDot(DOTstring);  --> vis is undefined
  ```
- in vis.min.js:

  ```
  (...)function o(t){return t&&t.__esModule?t:{default:t}}var n=i(2),s=o(n),r=i(55),a=o(r) (...) -> Expected identifier, string or number
  ```

The `vis.min.js` / `vis.min.css` and `draw_diagram.js` are loaded as static files in APEX (under Shared Components section) and defined in `HTML Header` section as follows:

```
<script src="#APP_IMAGES#vis#MIN#.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#APP_IMAGES#vis#MIN#.css" type="text/css">

<script src="#APP_IMAGES#draw_diagram.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In `Page Template Body` I've added the needed `div` in `Region Source` section:

```
<div id="my_network"></div>
```

However, when I apply the changes and go to the HTML page to see the result, I can see nothing but the above errors in the console.

I've also tried to load the files from CDN, but the result is the same.

The custom script looks like this:

```
var DOTstring = "some_dot_config_string_here";
var parsedData = vis.network.convertDot(DOTstring);
var container = document.getElementById('my_network');

var data = {
    nodes: parsedData.nodes,
    edges: parsedData.edges
};

var options = {
    layout: {
        hierarchical: {
            direction: "UD",
            sortMethod: "directed",
            nodeSpacing: 250
        }
    },
    physics: false,
    interaction: {
        dragNodes: false,
        dragView: true,
        navigationButtons: true
    }
};

// create a network
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
network.setSize('1800px', '840px');
network.redraw();
```

Any ideas on why this happens ?

Comment: What version of apex are you on? Also, can you verify the scripts have loaded in correctly by checking through the browser developer tools?

Comment: @Tom `Application Express 4.2.4.00.08`. And yes, the scripts are loaded corectly as you can see in [this image](http://i64.tinypic.com/ei2loj.png)

Comment: Not to try and be pedantic, but can you verify the modules have loaded correctly? For example, running from the dev tools console `vis` does return an actual object? Could you run your code from console?

Comment: @Tom when I'm running `vis` from dev tools, I get the same error: `'vis' is undefined`

Comment: @Tom any ideas on what's happening in here ? I can't seem to get my head around this. I cannot think of a single reason of why this wouldn't work. When I'm adding a simple `console.log("test")` it's printing it. However, it also display the first error message which says `Expected identifier, string or number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid an overly lengthy / unwieldy comment section, I'll post some things here and I'll update the answer as we go along

---

I'm not exactly sure, so instead I'll try to give some pointers to try out.

You're on apex 4.2. Don't use the HTML header to put your scripts tags in. You have dedicated fields to put script links in and the same goes for CSS.

Simply put

```
#APP_IMAGES#vis#MIN#.js
#APP_IMAGES#draw_diagram.js
```

In the javascript files box, and do the same for CSS.

There is a reason to prefer this. Scripts put here will be put near the end of the page, most likely, according to how the page template has been set up. It'll most likely be **after** the apex javascript (and dependencies) files, which is usually a good thing.

Mind you, you used `#MIN#` here. This means that when the page is NOT in debug mode, the minified file will be used. When in debug mode, the full source (not ´.min´) is used. Make sure you have both files available.

Verify modules have loaded. Don't just look at source html. Actually click on the links in the source html and see if you get the file you need, or see if you get an error in the dev console.

Verify the module or code loaded by running it from dev console. It's a simple check.

Are you sure there are no dependencies missing? Does vis need jquery for example?

Run the page in debug mode so you it will load the full source where available. This will save you from having to try and trawl through illegible minified code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tom. I'll write here what I've tried so far: I put each file in his own section as you suggested and the behaviour was exactly the same. After this, I completely removed the minified versions of vis.js and vis.css and added the full ones, so I also deleted the `#MIN#` from the path. Even after this, it was the same. More, I've clicked on each error and it seems it's able to access those files, thing that makes me think they are correct. I've also tried to add the jquery file and add it in front of everything. Still the same. :( Any other ideas ?

Comment: as a side note, I can't click the links in the source page because they look like this: `wwv_flow_file_mgr.get_file?p_security_group_id=855303257234618&p_flow_id=140&p_fname=vis.css`. But I'm able to click on the actual file which is just below the error: `File: wwv_flow_file_mgr.get_file, Line: 2521, Column: 33`. This would be the first error. The second one is about: `SCRIPT5009: 'vis' is undefined`. I don't know if it helps, but I'm running this on IE11.

Comment: So the very first js error in your console points to where exactly? In a vis file? Can you determine anything by it? Or is the very first error the error where vis is not defined? I'd be tempted to think that the initialization of vis itself would have to fail if it can't get assigned to the global variable.

Comment: The very first error (`Expected identifier`) points to the file `vis.js` which looks like this: `var _typeof = typeof _symbol2.default === "function" && typeof _iterator2.default === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof _symbol2.default === "function" && obj.constructor === _symbol2.default && obj !== _symbol2.default.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };`.I can't seem to figure what he doesn't like

Comment: I've gone and tested this in a 4.2.6 environment by adding vis.js and vis.min.js to the static files of a new, blank application, theme 26. On a page I've then added the file reference to the file urls, nothing more. Running the page goes without errors, and vis is accessible from the console. Could you try to perform the same? I'd just want to exclude any and all factors which could have an influence on this.

Comment: Could you please tell me exactly how your paths for the static files look like (did you added `#MIN` ? what version did you used ?)? Did you also test this on IE 11 ? ;P

Comment: Sure: `#APP_IMAGES#vis#MIN#.js`, I used the latest version from http://visjs.org/ , downloaded, uploaded vis.js and vis.min.js from /dist/ to app images (ergo I coupled an application to the file, otherwise it's a workspace file). I tested on IE11 and no problems.

Comment: Ok, so I've done the following. Removed every file and: - uploaded in static files section: `vis.min.css`, `vis.css`, `vis.min.js`, `vis.js`, and `draw_diagram.js`. Each of these were associated with the needed application. Then, in JS section I added: `#APP_IMAGES#vis#MIN#.js` and `#APP_IMAGES#draw_diagram.js` on separate lines. Then, in the css section I added `#APP_IMAGES#vis#MIN#.css`. Then, in the Regions section (Page template body) of the page, I added the required `<div>`: `<div id="my_network"></div>`. The same two errors occurred... :(

Comment: when you only attach the vis.js file, does it work then? just trying to reduce to barebones here